# Agregar Community Wikis

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Sería buena idea agregar algunas de las community Wikis que ya existen en StackOverflow en ingles, un ejemplo concreto estaba pensando en este caso de PHP

[Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Estan de acuerdo o cual sería la manera en que se manejaran las Community Wikis?

Cómo decir Community Wikis en español?

Comment: Wiki de la comunidad

Comment: *Community (No puedo editar, no me deja)

Comment: @JhonAlx necesitas tener cierta cantidad de reputación para poder editar =).

Comment: @Elenasys lo sé, pero en este sitio ya tengo la misma reputación que tengo en otros sitios como bicyclesSE y allá puedo editar sin problemas

Comment: @JhonAlx Saludos y bienvenido, creo que en este caso no es cosa de rep sino que esta la cola llena saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel, como dice Elenasys,  en los sites Meta solo podemos editar después de tener puntos suficientes (por [valores](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) de site beta o graduado).

Comment: @brasofilo tienes razón, en Meta de enSO tampoco puedo editar porque me faltan 31 puntos :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que si. Es el tipo de pregunta/respuesta que servirá para cerrar decenas de duplicatas.

Podemos marcar nuestras respuestas como Wiki de Comunidad (el permiso para editar es muy bajo y el autor original no gana puntos) **pero no podemos hacer lo mismo para preguntas**.

Para preguntas hay que pedir a un moderador o al *Community Manager* que lo haga; en general, pinchando en <kbd>reportar</kbd>, eligiendo `se necesita la intervención de un moderador` y explicando la situación; o usar el Chat para agilizar el proceso.

Cuando la pregunta está marcada como Wiki de Comunidad, todas las respuestas también estarán.